# Swift SKCropNode can someone explain this behavior?

Tags: swift, skcropnode

I have a grid of 16 SKCropNode objects. Each contains a SKShapeNode used as a mask, and a SKSpriteNoe. In this image with the mask not set you can see all 16 object appear in a grid.

https://github.com/soggybag/Grid

[image: Without mask all items appear]

[image: When the mask is set some of the items disappear? Seems there is a pattern here: 1, 4, 6, 9, 11, and 14. My guess is 17 would be gone.]

Interaction is strange also. Tapping makes the image sprite move down and disappear moving out of the mask. You can tap the area below the orange, where a sprite would be hidden, and it recognizes the tap event.

Even stranger you not tap the sprite in the upper right?